# How to use randomize links using php

Tags: php, html, arrays, hyperlink

I am using `array_rand()` to try and randomize 3 links. I basically want a different link to show up when the page is refreshed. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
$links = '<a href="http://google.com">google</a>, <a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>, <a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a>';
$links_to_array = preg_split("/ ,/", $links );
$randomize = array_rand($link_to_array, 1);
echo ($links_to_array[$randomize]);
```

So basically when I refresh it seem to work but sometimes all links show up at once. You can try it out yourself and let me know where I need to fix.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$links = '<a href="http://google.com">google</a>, <a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>, <a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a>';
$links_to_array = explode(", ", $links);
$randomize = array_rand($links_to_array, 1);
echo ($links_to_array[$randomize]);
```

Comment: this is what outputs when I use your code. googlefacebookgooglefacebookfacebookgooglegoogle thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @RonnyKibet I didn't understand you.., my code outputs only one random link. Or I not understand you correctly?

Comment: Oh! just tied it agan and it worked perfectly. thanks Winston. :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$links_to_array = preg_split("/, /", $links, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

---

**Update:**

```
$links = array('<a href="http://google.com">google</a>', 
               '<a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>', 
               '<a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a>');


echo $links[rand(0,2)]; // instead of 2 you can also write count($links)
```

Comment: Thanks powtac for that. All the links still show up though instead of one at random on every page refresh.

Comment: While using `preg_split()` better write like this `$links_to_array = preg_split("/, /", $links, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` to avoid empty elements in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are using preg_split with a space before the comma instead of comma before the space. Use `explode(',', $links)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This made some difference though all the links still show up. :(